# hi can anyone help me with my css assignment?

Tags: html, css

i have this code that i have to work on:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Advanced CSS - Assignment 1</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Main Heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">Google Doodles</a>
  <a href="https://www.link-group.eu/" target="_blank">Goto Link Group</a>
  <div id="first-div">
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <div id="second-div">
      <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
      <p>Paragraph 4</p>
      <p>Paragraph 5</p>
      <p>Paragraph 6</p>
      <p>Paragraph 7</p>
      <p>Paragraph 8</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 9</p>
  <p>Paragraph 10</p>
</body>

</html>
```

How can i change the first 2 links (google links) color green and the third one red without changing the code? i have to use the selectors and  pseudo classes. Can anyone tell me how to to that?

Comment: Can you add classes to `a` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research. Take the [tour] and read [ask] for more tips about this site and asking questions. See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: i dont think i can add classes..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-of-type()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Advanced CSS - Assignment 1</title>
  <style>
    a:nth-of-type(1),
    a:nth-of-type(2) {
      color: red;
    }
    
    a:nth-of-type(3) {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Main Heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">Google Doodles</a>
  <a href="https://www.link-group.eu/" target="_blank">Goto Link Group</a>
  <div id="first-div">
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <div id="second-div">
      <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
      <p>Paragraph 4</p>
      <p>Paragraph 5</p>
      <p>Paragraph 6</p>
      <p>Paragraph 7</p>
      <p>Paragraph 8</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 9</p>
  <p>Paragraph 10</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/Yzpprjw

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
/* This will match both google links because they both start with "https://www.google.com/" */
a[href^="https://www.google.com/"]{
    color: green;
}

/* This will exactly match "https://www.link-group.eu/" */
a[href="https://www.link-group.eu/"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">Google Doodles</a>
<a href="https://www.link-group.eu/" target="_blank">Goto Link Group</a>
<div id="first-div">
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <div id="second-div">
        <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
        <p>Paragraph 4</p>
        <p>Paragraph 5</p>
        <p>Paragraph 6</p>
        <p>Paragraph 7</p>
        <p>Paragraph 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
```

Comment: way to "complicated" for such assignment task. The use of `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` would the way more "simple" approach to solve it. Also there was no need to change the links to block level elements. PS: The downvote is not for being technical wrong (your solution clearly works) but missing simplicity for the task in combination with changing to unwanted block level elements.

Comment: @tacoshy I removed the `display:block`. That was a left-over from my initial draft where I only included the `a` elements in my snipped. Now, how exactly are they too "complicated"? The OP didn't state what method to use. Since both google links are supposed to be green and no classes can be used, my initial thought was selecting by href. One selector for both google links, and one selector for the other link. Also we can't tell if the page contains other links as well. The method I proposed is safe in any case.

Comment: yes its not complicated for you or me or any good programmer. The thing about assignment tasks are, that they are rated for simple solutions. If the links would change for example then the solution might not be valid anymore. as such imho the `:nth`selector solution is the most simple but also effiecient way to solve the issue for all cases.

Comment: @tacoshy Yes I agree with the first part. I just don't agree with "`to solve the issue for all cases.`" tho. I edited my previous comment. If there are indeed multiple links on the site, all other solutions (by the time of writing this) won't work anymore. The `href` selector works with any `a` quantity. But since the OP stated that his problem is resolved, there were no additional links, so that's that. Thank you for your clarification tho (and for retracting the downvote) :)

Answer (score 0):

`a:nth-child(any number here)`

```css
a:nth-child(1), a:nth-child(2){
  color: green;
}
a:nth-child(3){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">Google Doodles</a>
<a href="https://www.link-group.eu/" target="_blank">Goto Link Group</a>
```

Comment: thank you it seems to work here but when i put it in visual code and test it, the first link was red and the rest blue wtf is going on

Comment: You probably have other `a`s in your code. try `body > a:nth-child(any number)` maybe that will help.